# I'm tired of listening to you argue! 'listening to+you+verb' here, which sentence structure has been followed?

Tags: grammar

I'm tired of listening to you argue!

**'listening to+you+verb'**  which sentence structure has been followed here?

I think, it's supposed to be **"your argue".**

Comment: No it's not supposed to be "your argue".  The sentence is correct as written.  It doesn't need to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tired of listening to you argue. [plural or singular can be presumed]

I'm tired of listening to you arguing. [same thing]

I'm tired of listening to your arguing. [same thing]

Just about any verb related to "tired of listening to" would work:
argue, fight, bellow, etc.

In English, we use *your plus a present participle or you plus a present particle.*

Your arguing bores me.
You arguing [with your brother] bores me.

Answer (score -1):

It’s not quite correct English; it should be “I’m tired of listening to you arguing”, but it is close enough to be accepted.

Same structure as “I’m tired of listening to you playing loud music”. Some people make a lot of noise, and I tell them that I don’t want to listen to them anymore as they make their noise.